# How do I pass back a date to an Activity from a DialogFragment / DatePickerFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I know how to do this with Intent, but how do I do this....

Here is the code I have to open the `DatePickerFragment`:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("date", (String) itemDict.get(Helper.convertKeyString(name, false)));
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Once that is open, how do I pass the date I choose back to my `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `interface`, pass it to `DatePickerFragment` (in constructor), and then call method in before closing the dialog

For example:

Your interface:

```
public interface OnDatePicked{
    void onDatePicked();
}
```

Your Activity:

```
public YourActivity implements OnDatePicked{
    //your Activity
}
```

And your DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment { //change Object to required type
    private OnDatePicked listener;

    public DatePickerFragment(OnDatePickedlistener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    //required methods
    protected void method(Object o){
        //your stuff
        listener.onDatePicked();
    }
}
```